# How to change a PDF file's "/Rotate" key to 0 and not change PDF visually using Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer

For someone that worked with PDF files for years that is probably an easy one, so here's my problem:

I processed several PDF files with my Python script using pdfminer.six and I now came across files with a value of "90" in the "/Rotate" key.
This totally ruined my script, although the orientation of the PDF is correct when I open it up in any PDF viewer.
I was successful with something called "cpdf" and the function "-upright" but since it is not Python I wont integrate this into my script.

So what I need to do, is to set the "/Rotate" key to 0 before processing it.

Any ideas how to do this using pdfminer(.six) and/or PyPDF2/4 ?

Comment: To be clear, I need the PDF to stay as it is with the rotation but to save it with a new zero value for rotation. So it basically gets a new baseline or new orientation.

Comment: That is because pdfminer doesnt care about the rotation and gives me coordinates which then do not match later. Alternatively I could rotate these coordinates somehow to match the rotated PDF...

Comment: Slowly I am superconfused, sorry about that. So pdfminer DOES care about the rotation if given to it properly. What it then does, it totally messes with my alogrithm of finding things on that PDF. Is there a possibility to for example convert the "old" coordinates (X1/Y1) to the rotated PDF?

Comment: You can't just set the rotate key to 0, that would make it look wrong in all PDF viewers. You need to set the rotate key to 0 and apply the rotation to all objects in all page streams. On top of that you will have the change the page boxes (mediabox etc...) to match your new orientation.

Comment: Yes, I get that now that the rotation was set by someone to set the correct orientation in the PDF. Setting /Rotate to 0 will just set the PDF to a wrong orientation...
So how to set the PDF to a new and directly correct orientation without rotation?

Comment: Or alternatively is there a way of converting (X/Y) points which I extract out of the PDF when (0/0) is in the bottom left corner to when its in the upper-left?

Comment: That would be the second part of my comment: "You need to set the rotate key to 0 and apply the rotation to all objects in all page streams. On top of that you will have the change the page boxes (mediabox etc...) to match your new orientation." The PDF specification contains the exact rotation implied by this key (which can not only be 90 but also 180 and 270)

Comment: Not really. My workaround now is to check for that /Rotate value and in the end convert the detected coordinates (X1/Y1) to (PDFHEIGHT-Y1/X1).